# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xebba1b0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I understand the reason why  `message sent to deallocated instance 0xebba1b0` is called, it is because I am sending a message to an object which is no longer in memory.

So here's my scenario. I have a ZoomedViewController which has a UITableView in it. The UITableView has a custom UITableViewCell, which has an attributed label as a subview. When a link is pressed on the attributed label (which in turns triggers didSelectRowAtIndexPath) it delegates to my MainViewController and calls the method closeZoomedImageVC in MainViewController:

```
-(void) closeZoomedImageVC
{
    [self.zoomedImageContainer_ removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.zoomedImageContainer_.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

the issue is that when that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is triggered, then zoomedImageContainer_ is already gone. How do I solve this then?

To illustrate the point better, basically when I do:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(closeZoomedImageVC) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

this doesn't cause the crash anymore, but this is not a solution as it is hacky. What this does is it lets didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be executed first before it is deallocated.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that when you tap on the link, you also send a touch event to the table view, and doing that causes this error?

Comment: yes.. doing that causes this error because at that point removeFromSuperview and removeFromParentView calls dealloc in which in turns free's up the tableView and then after the tableView is freed then that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.. then BOOM.. crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference to your `UITableView` in `ZoomedViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Make sure to connect the outlet in Interface Builder. Now, when your `zoomedImageContainer_.view` is removed, it won't dealloc the `UITableView` until you release that reference as well.

You also need to store a `strong` reference to your `ZoomedViewController` in `MainViewController`, and only set that to `nil` after you have saved the selected row back in `MainViewController`.

Comment: I am not using ARC yet.. but actually I am calling release on the tableview on dealloc

Comment: That's okay, you can do it there, but the issue is you're calling `dealloc` too early. You need to hang onto the `ZoomedViewController` until you've processed the selection and then allow it to `dealloc`.

Comment: yes.. I agree that is the solution, but how do I remove the ZoomedImageViewController after that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is done?

Comment: Make the `ZoomedViewController` call a method on `MainViewController` that tells it the selection has been processed. The code in `MainViewController` can then safely set `zoomedImageContainer_ = nil;`

Comment: One clean way I can think off is in the dealloc method I would need to cancel that call to didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but is that even possible?

Comment: Basically, you should be calling `closeZoomedImageVC` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, not in response to the link being pressed.

Comment: if I just tap the cell, in which it calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath I do not want to close the zoomedImageViewController.. I only want to close it when I tap on the links

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15997/discussion-between-xonegirlz-and-darvids0n)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to, I'm quite busy at work. I would suggest you set a `BOOL shouldCloseZoomedImageVC` somewhere on `MainViewController`, set it to `YES` when a link is tapped, and periodically check it (say once a second with an `NSTimer`). If yes, `closeZoomedImageVC`. OR you can set your `delegate` to `nil` before closing the VC if you don't care about processing the `didSelectRow..` call at that point.

Comment: Actually I have found a solution, which is to set the tableview.allowSelection = NO. This then causes the didSelectRowAtIndexPath not to be called

Comment: +1. In my case I was instantiating a MyTableViewController in another hosting view controller. The instance was a local variable that went out of scope. I made the instance a property (strong, nonatomic) and it works. Your answer gave the sudden insight I needed.

Answer (score 0):

When tapping on a cell in a table will invoke an animation to highlight selected cell, and it needs a short duration complete, so the best way is what you are doing, perform selector after a delay, I think 0.5 second is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my self is to just set the allowSelection = NO in the tableView property. This will let the attributedLabel inside the UITableViewCell to have interaction but will disable didSelectRowAtIndexPath being called